# Compare lists of genes

Tags: statistical-significance, computational-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have two lists of differentially expressed genes: the list 1 was derived from the universe A of total genes while the list 2 was derived from the universe B of total genes. A number of genes is in common between the two lists. I would like to quantitatively measure the overlap, for example with a p-Value of significance. The Fisher test I suppose is the solution when the universe is the same (i.e. the total number of screened genes) while in this case the universes are different. Is there a statistical test that is appropriate for this situation. I'm not a statistician.

ex: list1: 1500 genes derived from an universe of 14.440 genes and list2: 1200 genes derived from an universe of 13250 genes. Overlap: 250 genes. My question is: is that overlap statistically significant?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately the numbers are different. I just edited.

Comment: What is your null hypothesis that you want to test here? Overlap of 250 genes needs to be compared with how much overlap that will be considered insignificant?

Comment: To be honest I have not a null hypothesis. I just would like to quantify the overlap with respect to both lists and both universes. For example 250 genes could represent a good overlap in the case of lists of 400 genes (more than 50%) but what about in the case of 1500 and 1200 genes composing the two lists respectively?

Comment: ah ok. 13250 genes of universe B are all contained in universe A.

Comment: It may be useful if we know more about the background of these 2 'universes' of genes. Are you studying some species and subspecies etc or some diseases? This may help to decide which statistical analysis to be performed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hypergeometric distribution to see the probability of A containing 250 or more "successes" (ie members for list B) from the union of universe A and B. This is a standard and computationally fast way to do pathway enrichment or overrepresentation analysis (google those things for lots more methods).

You could also construct a simulation study where you randomly draw lists A and B from universe A and B and the one sided p value will be how many times you get as much or more overlap then you did. This would allow you to avoid using the union but will be much more computationally intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Following appears to be the picture:

[image]

But you need to have a null hypothesis to test if overlap of 250 is significant from null hypothesis.

Comment: Ok, I get the point.  What I would like to test is if list1 is sufficiently different or equal to the list2 according to the overlapping genes. H0 is: they are equal.